# Не получается сравнить массив ни с чем в java

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Задача (Task):

> Evaluate a given floor of the casino to determine if there is a guard between the money and the thief, if there is not, you will sound an alarm.

Input Format:

> A string of characters that includes $ (money), T (thief), and G (guard), that represents the layout of the casino floor.
>   Space on the casino floor that is not occupied by either money, the thief, or a guard is represented by the character x.

Сначала я пробовал сравнивать индекс элементов массива, через indexOf,  в ответ массив выдавал: -1, на любой элемент, потом я сравнивал сам массив с "TG$", он не сравнивает, хотя в систем аут показывает именно так, пробовал сравнивать и массивы , создал второй массив и через equals пытался из сравнить, все равно не видит, почему-то.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> arr =
                new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sc.nextLine().split("x")));
        for (String n : arr) {
            String r = new String("TGS");
            if (arr.contains(r)) {
                System.out.print("yess");
            } else {
                System.out.print("peshalll'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "TGS" это совсем не то же самое, что "TG$".

Comment: Я знаю, я ввожу TG$ конечно всегда, просто тут так написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Умение пользоваться отладчиком сильно упрощает жизнь, советую освоить этот инструмент и активно им пользоваться в непонятных ситуациях.

Ваш код возвращает массив из пустых элементов, вместо строки, которой вы ожидаете.

```
ArrayList<String> arr = 
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xxxxxx$xxxxxxxTxxxxxxxxGxxxxxx".split("x")));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если хотите получить нужную вам строку, тогда лучше просто убрать все `х` через replace, заодно выкинете ненужный цикл.

```
String test = "xxxxxx$xxxxxxxTxxxxxxxxGxxxxxx".replace("x", "");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Ну или в качестве задачки для размышления подумайте, как вам сделать то, что вы хотите, через перебор массива.

Comment: Так эту строку вводит пользователь, я не могу заранее знать, какая это строка, поэтому использую динамический массив, я не могу использовать в качестве приема данных от пользователя использовать строку.

Comment: Либо тогда преобразовать массив от пользователя в строку и там сделать replace?

Comment: Правда преобразовывать массив в строку и сравнивать строки тоже пробовал.

Comment: @ЭмильМаннапов ну так вы же сейчас так и делаете, получаете от пользователя строку `sc.nextLine()` и вам по идее ничего не мешает написать `String str = sc.nextLine();`. Вы уже её принимаете, просто потом её зачем-то преобразуете в `ArrayList`.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, массив там и не нужен)